# Is this a redundant NullPointerException catch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, model-view-controller

Below Spring REST code returns List for a given ticketId.

Could a `NullPointerException` be thrown in this code ?

`NullPointerException` explicitly caught in `TicketController`:

```
    catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, nullPointerException.getMessage(), nullPointerException);
    }
```

The thinking may have been when checking for null on the ticket id:

```
        if (ticketId == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "ticket id cannot be null");
        }
```

the expectation is that a `NullPointerException` would be thrown but instead a `ResponseStatusException` is thrown ?

If the variable `ticketId` is a path parameter it can never be null as hit the base url `/` without a `ticketId` I receive:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
```

Entire source:

```
@RestController
    public class TicketController {

        private final TicketServiceImpl ticketServiceImpl;

        public TicketController(TicketServiceImpl ticketServiceImpl) {
            this.ticketServiceImpl = ticketServiceImpl;
        }

        @GetMapping(path = "/{ticketId}")
        public ResponseEntity<List<TicketResponse>> getTicketsById(
            @PathVariable("ticketId") final Long ticketId) {
            try {
                final List<TicketResponse> ticketsById = ticketServiceImpl.getAll(ticketId);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(ticketsById, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, nullPointerException.getMessage(), nullPointerException);
            }
            catch (TicketNotFoundException ticketNotFoundException) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Ticket id not found",
                    ticketNotFoundException);
            }

        }

    }

@Service
public class TicketServiceImpl implements TicketService {

    private final TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    public TicketServiceImpl(TicketRepository ticketRepository) {

        this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;

    }

    @Override
    public List<TicketResponse> getAll(Long ticketId) {

        final List<TicketResponse> ticketResponselist = ticketRepository.findData(ticketId);

            if (ticketId == null) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "ticket id cannot be null");
            }
            else if (ticketResponselist.size() == 0) {
                throw new TicketNotFoundException("ticket not found");
            }
            else {
                return ticketResponselist;
            }

    }
}

@Repository
public interface TicketRepository {

    public List<TicketResponse> findData(Long ticketId);

}
```

Comment: Although throwing exceptions takes time, that's generally not a performance concern. Putting exceptions in a catch clause is not that slow. So the question becomes: 1. why do you care and 2. how did you test? Are you sure that for no framework / situation that the `NullPointerException` can be thrown? If it can then it certainly makes sense to generate a higher level / checked exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if (ticketId == null)` check should happen before the `ticketRepository.findData(ticketId);` is called.

Otherwise, the validation doesn't make sense.

Also, as a side note, catching `NullPointerException` is a bad practice. The reason is that having a null pointer exception thrown is mostly a sign of a coding smell. The code should be null-safe, by either using e.g. [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) or having a proper validation at the method level. In this case, it would be at the route level (which is the external input). From that point onward, if the validation is set, you're dealing with non nullable id.

This is also somehow related to returning null from a method, which is also a bad practice, since it requires a check in every method which then uses the returned value. This would pollute the code, will introduce a new level of abstraction, and will generally lead to nasty bugs.

Comment: @loan thank you, can the ticketId ever be null ? From queestion: "If the variable ticketId is a path parameter it can never be null as hit the base url / without a ticketId I receive:

There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405)."

Comment: I think that's more of an implementation detail about how spring handles this. It can be null also if e.g. the path parameter is not a number (some random string), the Long value will for sure not be truthy.

Comment: @loan do you mean the path parameter value? If a String is passed to the ticketId path parameter which is not a valid number  then a numberFormatException will be thrown, rather than nullPointerException.

Comment: Then it looks like the NullPointerException cannot be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException check is not required in this case.

Side note : Its better to use the super type when passing as a method parameter until and unless you are pretty sure that no exception will be thrown instead of yours.